# Update multiple values with where exists clause

Tags: plsql, where-clause

I have this problem with PL/SQL.
I have 2 tables with same columnus.
One is for Current Run, the other for history.

At every run, I need to update history with just values that I found in current run.

**Current Table**

```
|   ID  |__NAME__|__SURNAME__|__CITY__|
| 10000 |  ABC   |   CDE     |   IT   |
| 10001 |  EFG   |   ASD     |   EN   |
| 10005 |        |           |        |
```

**History Table**

```
|   ID  |__NAME__|__SURNAME__|__CITY__|
| 10000 |  FFF   |    AAA    |   EN   |
| 10001 |  DDD   |    BBB    |   GR   |
| 10005 |  JKO   |    POI    |   GR   |
| 10006 |  DLK   |    MIN    |   IT   |
```

As you can see, **Current Table** has a record with all empty values except ID=10005.
So, I need to update history (name, surname, city) from current table where id exists in current table and name, surname and city are not null.

I've tried with

```
UPDATE HISTORY
    SET (NAME, SURNAME, CITY) = (
        SELECT NAME, SURNAME, CITY
        FROM CURRENT temp
        WHERE temp.name is not null and temp.id = history.id
        )
    WHERE exists (
        SELECT NAME, SURNAME, CITY
        FROM CURRENT temp
        WHERE temp.name is not null and temp.id = history.id
    );
```

But it doesn't work.
I need to underline that when name is null in current table, then surname and city are also null.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgres?

Comment: PLSQL- I'm going to edit my question

Comment: Do you mean Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the only wrong thing in your query is the name of the table CURRENT. It is a reserved word in oracle and is not recommended to use it as table name. You have to use "" this to work. Here:

```
UPDATE HISTORY
    SET (NAME, SURNAME, CITY) = (
        SELECT NAME, SURNAME, CITY
        FROM "CURRENT" temp
        WHERE temp.name is not null and temp.id = history.id
        )
    WHERE exists (
        SELECT NAME, SURNAME, CITY
        FROM "CURRENT" temp
        WHERE temp.name is not null and temp.id = history.id
    );
```

You can use [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) too (See the explain plan for both):

```
MERGE INTO HISTORY_TABLE a
     USING (SELECT ID, NAME, SURNAME, CITY
              FROM CURRENT_TABLE
             WHERE NAME IS NOT NULL) b
        ON (a.id = b.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET a.NAME = b.NAME, a.SURNAME = b.SURNAME, a.CITY = b.CITY
```